# ERROR HTTPError: 400 Bad Request when building PyPi package

Tags: python, package, pypi, python-packaging

I'm trying to build my PyPi package and after I ran this command `python3 -m twine upload --verbose --repository testpypi dist/*` it gave me this error:

```
Response from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/:                                                                                                                                                                                         
         400 '0+untagged.2.g592d0aa' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can't use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.                                            
INFO     <html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          <head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           <title>400 '0+untagged.2.g592d0aa' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can't use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.</title>                           
          </head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
          <body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
           <h1>400 '0+untagged.2.g592d0aa' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can't use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.</h1>                                 
           The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.<br/><br/>                                                                                                                        
         &#x27;0+untagged.2.g592d0aa&#x27; is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can&#x27;t use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         </html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ERROR    HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/                                                                                                                                                                        
         '0+untagged.2.g592d0aa' is an invalid value for Version. Error: Can't use PEP 440 local versions. See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for more information.
```

I used `--verbose` to get more information about my error. For my setup.py I used the following for version:

```
setup(
    name='fsa_test_one',
    version=versioneer.get_version(),
    cmdclass=versioneer.get_cmdclass()
```

Comment: The version format is incorrect. Take a look at the [spec](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#version) and set the version accordingly.

Comment: I used versioneer to set my version, should I put it manually following the PEP440 specification?

Comment: Manual versioning is a start, just to get you unblocked. You should also create an issue in the versioneer project since it is supposed to create PEP 440 compliant versions and I bet you're not the only person to have this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the version manually to get things started I changed the `version=versioneer.get_version()` to `version="1.0"` in the setup.py file but i'm still getting the same error. Any advice would be highly appreciated. I will be posting on versioneer shortly

Comment: I think the generated version would pass if the public version included a minor and last segment was removed, `0.0+untagged.2`, but it's just a guess.

Comment: `1.0` is valid according to [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#examples-of-compliant-version-schemes)

Comment: Are there any existing versions of the package in the repository? If so, the root cause may be due to ordering.

Comment: I found the error, I used PEP440 instead of PEP440-pre and also I had previous builds saved in the dist/* directory and so it was giving me error even though I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the `versioneer` style, it is found in the `setup.cfg` file I changed that to the style that supports my package which is `PEP440-pre`. So after changing that I had to setup versioneer again and then it worked. I also had to make sure I removed all the previous builds stored in the `dist/*` directory